# Wix: Feature tree selections cause Browse button to disappear

Tags: wix

In my installer, I have two features. If I disable one feature, the Browse button (and the edit control containing the INSTALLDIR path) disappears from the UI. I suspect this is because both Feature elements use the same ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" attribute:

```
    <Feature Id="MYCLIENT" AllowAdvertise="no" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR"
        Title="Client component"
        Description="Client Component" Level="1">

        <ComponentGroupRef="Client1"/>

    </Feature>

    <Feature Id="MYMMC" AllowAdvertise="no" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR"
        Title="MMC Components"
        Description="MMC Components" Level="1">

        <ComponentGroupRef Id="MMC1"/>

        <!-- MMC snap-in requires some client components -->
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="Client1"/>

    </Feature>
```

What would I need to implement to prevent the INSTALLDIR Browse controls from disappearing when a feature is de-selected/not installed ?

TIA

Comment: Is INSTALLDIR correct or should it be INSTALLLOCATION?

Comment: `Configurable` can refer to whatever `Directory Id` ...for example: `<Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="Main Feature" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="TARGETDIR">`

Comment: Thank you, @MikeQuentel! This was exactly what I was looking for. Just adding the ConfigurableDirectory attribute did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browse button is related to the selected feature in the tree. If you have excluded some feature and it is still selected, it is logical that there is no sense to set install path for this feature. So Browse button is disabled. I suppose when you select another feature in the tree, the Browse button will appear again.

By the way, why do you need the same ConfigurableDirectory for both features? That's a bit strange to install 2 main parts of the system in the same folder. I usually make a root Feature with ConfigurableDirectory while all sub-features can only be installed in predefined sub-folders. On the other hand, if you really need to set different locations for 2 features, you'd rather use differect ConfigurableDirectories.